# Updating Array elements with out blocking entire array

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

Which Java Concurrent collection provide Array element level locking or atomic updation of Array elements. I do not want to lock entire array. there is 99% read operations and only 1% write operations only.

Locking while writing in array will block may other threads which even might not be looking at the same element which is being updated by blocking thread.

Comment: Have you profiled your code and found this to be a bottleneck in practice? If not, this is premature optimization and probably more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: How complex is the write operation?  What are the array elements, integers or an object with complex, amybe blocking, write methods?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `AtomicXxxArray` where each element can be atomically updated with appropriate visibility guarantees:

- [AtomicIntegerArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html)
- [AtomicLongArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLongArray.html)
- [AtomicReferenceArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReferenceArray.html)